# "nativehr" error while trying to delete list items through ProcessBatchData

Tags: 2013, development, splistitem, batch

Plain and simple, I'm trying to delete a massive amount of items from a list as quickly as possible using a c# app, and have seen references to batch processes being the best way to do this. Not knowing much about them I've used examples online from places like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/eb4e03ff-001a-4500-adfb-cfcbe9b3b57c/deleting-all-items-from-an-splist-with-c-) but keep running into the error `<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>` when the application reaches the `SPWeb.ProcessBatchData` step. Here is my code:

```
SPListItemCollection oCol = oList.Items;
StringBuilder sbDelete = new StringBuilder("<Batch>");
sbDelete.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"? >");
sbDelete.Append("<ows:Batch OnError=\"Return\">");
for (int x = oCol.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    sbDelete.Append("<Method>");
    sbDelete.Append("<SetList Scope=\"Request\">" + oList.ID.ToString() + "</SetList>");
    sbDelete.Append("<SetVar Name=\"ID\">" + oCol[x].ID.ToString() + "</SetVar>");
    sbDelete.Append("<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar>");
    sbDelete.Append("</Method>");
}
sbDelete.Append("</ows:Batch>");
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
oWeb.ProcessBatchData(sbDelete.ToString());
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I've tried multiple approaches recommended by sources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323983/nativehr0x80070057-nativehrnativestack-nativestack-when-creating-a-choic) and [this](http://www.programmingrelief.com/2100583/Sharepoint-Processbatchdata-Update-Nativehr-0x80070057) but with no luck. The only theory I have is that the batch ends up being too big, but if so, what is the limit?

Answer (score 1):

When I use web service operations for batch processing in 2010, my batch looks much different:

```
    <Batch OnError='Continue'>
      <Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'>
        <Field Name='ID'>1234</Field>
      </Method>
<Method ID='2' Cmd='Delete'>
        <Field Name='ID'>1235</Field>
      </Method>
    </Batch>
```

I don't know if that makes a difference in 2013 and in your implementation.

Comment: I'll restructure the batch to look more like yours and see if that helps. I can't find any documentation on the differences between 10 and 13 in this regard, so it's pretty much just a "guess and check" situation unfortunately

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This one is for Google search users like me:

```
    public static void DeleteItemsUsingBatch(SPWeb web, String ListName)
    {

        bool allowUnsafe = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;

        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPList list = web.Lists[ListName];

        SPListItemCollection listItem = list.GetItems(new SPQuery());
        StringBuilder sbDelete = new StringBuilder();
        sbDelete.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Batch>");

        int methodID = 0;
        foreach (SPListItem item in listItem)
        {
            sbDelete.AppendFormat("<Method ID=\"{0}\">" +
                                          "<SetList>{1}</SetList>" +
                                          "<SetVar Name=\"ID\">{2}</SetVar>" +
                                          "<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar>" +
                                          "</Method>",
                                          methodID, //{0}
                                          list.ID, //{1}
                                          item.ID //{2}
                                          );
            methodID++;
        }
        sbDelete.Append("</Batch>");

        string delete = sbDelete.ToString();

        web.ProcessBatchData(delete);
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafe;
    }
```

Comment: What is your source for that? It looks pretty much the same as one of the sources I linked (though apparently the link is now broken).

Comment: I dont remember where i got it, i had it in my personal util class for a long time. "<Method ID=\"{0}\">" <-- method in your code was missing an ID attribute. i suspect that was the reason for error.